# Pass another parameter to Fulcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

Here is the code, the "events: url," part of the code is coming through into my fullcalendar.js file and adds the events however I also want to add a list of users from json data like so users:'urlusers'

Will I have to edit the fullcalendar.js file and if so where can I add another parameter for the users.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
minTime: "08:00:00",
maxTime: "20:00:00",
editable:false, 
header:{
 left:'prev,next today',
 center:'title',

},
events: 'https://events.com/eventsjson',
users:'https://events.com/usersjson',
selectable:true,
selectHelper:true,
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
 var titlestart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm:ss");


 var r = confirm("Request Time " + titlestart);
 if (r == true) {
           event.preventDefault();
           //Open dialog
        var subject = 'Booking '+titlestart;
        var emailBody = 'Create booking for '+titlestart    
           showDialog(titlestart);
 } else {

 }
},
});
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the list of users for? What will you do with it? fullCalendar has no concept of "users". If you can explain the purpose of the data and functionality you want to achieve then maybe we can suggest a suitable approach.

Comment: I have created a table with a list of users, I can hard code by event.id to set the colour of event biased on that, however if I can pass the user json data into the fullcalendar.js file I can dynamically go though each users in a loop im on v3.4 on full calendar and on line approx 2700  getSegClasses: function (t, e, n) {) is where I am changing colour.

Comment: Basically I want to add the "users" field to the full calendar exactly like the "events", I have the JavaScript locally and want to add a users field to the fullcalendar and have it work very similar to the events where I pass in an array of users like I pass in an array of events.

Comment: You mean you want to set each event to a different colour depending on which user it belongs to? I assume you have some data which associates an event to a specific user, then? Is that all held in your database? Do you use PHP code to generate the JSON?

Comment: Yeah, got it read through the documentation and added more data to the JSON file to include backgroundColor, borderColor and textColour, I can now create a user and set the values of each of these thanks for the suggestion work a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution I was thinking of but got the result.

on the events: 'https://events.com/eventsjson', I needed to add more data to the JSON then the fullcalendar sorted the rest out for me

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
     'id'   => $row["user_id"],
     'start'   => $row["startevent"],
     'end'   => $row["endevent"],
     'backgroundColor'   => $row["backgroundColor"],
     'borderColor'   => $row["borderColor"]
    );
}
```

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, but glad you got the hint and figured it out!